# Forms generated through admin in Django

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I need to be able to create forms from admin panel. Process would look like this:
I click on "Add form" then I enter email to which the form should be sent and of course several fields (probably thanks to inlines) consisting of field name, type and if it is required. User should be able to view and fill the form and submit it and the data should be sent to the email given in admin.

Everything looks pretty straightforward but from my point of view it need some metaclass programming skills.

Could anyone point me to a goot form builder for Django or at least hand some tips about creating such thing? I found [django-forms-builder](http://code.google.com/p/django-forms-builder/) but it is a bit too restricted imho.

Comment: It might help if you explain what you find restrictive about django-forms-builder, because it seems that it does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: The real problem is, in forms_builder I need to enter static list of fields that then can be added to the constructed form. I need a way to dynamically compose forms and their fields.

Answer (score 5):

I know this one's a few months old but I just though I'd post an update here anyway for anyone else that comes along.

django-forms-builder has just been rewritten to do exactly what you were looking for when you originally posted this question.

You can find the new version at http://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder or http://bitbucket.org/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this asap.
By the time I used http://github.com/cuker/django-form-designer which works VERY good. Besides, it can be plugged into Django-CMS :)

Comment: Interestingly I've done the same thing and integrated django-forms-builder into Mezzanine which is another Django based CMS. You can check out a live demo of it at http://mezzanine.jupo.org

Answer (score 5):

There are many alternatives, although not many of them are actively maintained:

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/form-builder/

If you want to have a full control of what's happening (change fields for your needs or add new ones, add captcha or honeypot, add custom handling of form data, use form wizards or even use your forms via web REST API), use `django-fobi` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fobi